# How does CPI respond to change in shipping costs?

Tags: reference-request, inflation, international-trade, welfare-economics

Is there any quality research that already attempted to quantify the effect of shipping costs on CPI or inflation? Preferably I am looking for an estimate relevant to EU (however, I understand there might not be EU specific estimates so I am also willing to accept answer with global, or US estimates). I am working on a project that tries to predict the effects of supply chain disruptions caused by Houthi movement in Yemen on EU economy. I am looking for something like 'elasticity of CPI' with respect shipping costs. Does anyone know of some paper or technical report that has such estimates?